# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n · b_n) $ converges absolutely true or false?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $  be a convergent series and let $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n $ be absolutely convergent. Then $  \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n · b_n) $ converges absolutely I know it is true but having hard time to write a proof ... thanks in advance !

Comment: True. $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: can u help me by sharing any begining for a proof ?

Comment: You should only need $a_n$ bounded.

Comment: Can you help us stating clearly *in the body of your question* what you want to ask?

Comment: I just wrote I know it is true but having hard time to write a proof

Comment: And how do you know it's true, then?

Comment: I saw an answer published online but didn't understand it ...

Comment: What techniques are available to you to prove that a series is absolutely convergent?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $|a_n\cdot b_n|=|a_n||b_n|\le K|b_n|$, and the $K$ comes from the fact that the series of $a_n$ converges hence the $n^{th}$ term $a_n \to 0$ hence is bounded by $K > 0$. So $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_nb_n| \le K\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_n|$, and converges by comparison test as the series of $b_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Is it true to say that if $ \lim an = 0 $ then $ \lim |an| = 0 ? $

Comment: @sirepsilon: Yes it is because $|a_n| = \sqrt{a_n^2}\to \sqrt{0^2} = 0$.